# Cache sql server data in asp.net until row is modified

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2008

I frequently run queries in the form of:

```
select * from SomeTable where id=12345
```

Page after page I may be running that same query because the user needs to values for that row. Normally I would fetch it once and cache it, but the user can change the row at any time and other users are also making changes in SomeTable at the same time so I can't cache against the whole table. I also have the problem that we have a cluster for webservers so I can't track internally on the webserver when the cache has become invalidated.

Is there any way to detect that a change has occurred in this row? Can SqlDependecyCache class help here for individual rows to multiple web servers? Is there some trigger or other paradigm that can notify my web applications?

I want the best of both worlds - real time cache updates on the webservers, but I don't want to run any queries to see if the row has changed because I could just as easily fetch the row again.

Answer (score 3):

What you need is to enable SqlCacheDependency as @RenusRusanu mentioned.

I have several working examples [on my Github site](https://github.com/jupaol/LearningProjects/tree/master/VS%202012/src/WebForms/MSTS%2070-515/Msts/Topics/Chapter02/Lesson03), feel free to browse 
*[the code under my LearningProjects](https://github.com/jupaol/LearningProjects)* (*3rd party edit*)

- [Caching SQL queries](https://github.com/jupaol/LearningProjects/blob/master/VS%202012/src/WebForms/MSTS%2070-515/Msts/Topics/Chapter02/Lesson03/CachingSqlQueries.aspx.cs)
- [Page OutputCache declaratively](https://github.com/jupaol/LearningProjects/blob/master/VS%202012/src/WebForms/MSTS%2070-515/Msts/Topics/Chapter02/Lesson03/OutputCacheWithSqlPollingDeclaratively.aspx)
- [Page OutputCache in code](https://github.com/jupaol/LearningProjects/blob/master/VS%202012/src/WebForms/MSTS%2070-515/Msts/Topics/Chapter02/Lesson03/OutputCacheWithSqlPollingDependency.aspx.cs)

You need to configure the database first in order to use SqlCacheDependency:

In order to use a SQL Dependency, we need to configure basically two things in the database:

1. Create the database infrastructure which consists on a table, and store procedures, to configure it we use the `aspnet_regsql.exe` as follows:

   ```
   /* For SQL Server authentication... */
   aspnet_regsql.exe -S server -U user -P password -d database -ed
   /* For Windows Authentication... */
   aspnet_regsql.exe -S server -E -d database -ed
   ```
2. Create the polling information which consists to specify the table to monitor and a trigger to that table to populate the infrastructure table needed

   ```
       /* For SQL Server authentication... */
           aspnet_regsql.exe -S server
          -U user -P password -d database -t tableName -et
           /* For Windows Authentication... */
          aspnet_regsql.exe -S server
          -E -d database -t tableName -et
   ```

Code configuration

```
        var s = new SqlCacheDependency("AdventureWorks", "Product");

        HttpContext.Current.Cache.Insert(
            "products", 
            h, 
            s, 
            Cache.NoAbsoluteExpiration, 
            Cache.NoSlidingExpiration);
```

The `AdventureWorks` name is the name of the sql dependency configured in the web.config file

```
<caching>
  <sqlCacheDependency enabled="true" pollTime="30000" >
    <databases>
      <add 
           name="AdventureWorks"
           connectionStringName="AdventureWorksPolling" />
    </databases>
  </sqlCacheDependency>
</caching>
```

The `pollTime` can be configured in the `<add ...` element and will override the global `polltime`

### Alternatively you can rely on the SqlDataSource control

In order to enable caching when using this control, you need to set the `DataSourceMode` property to `DataSet`. In this case, you do not need to configure the database as explained before

[I just uploaded this example (full working example)](https://github.com/jupaol/SO-Answers/blob/master/Visual%20Studio%202012/src/SO/WebForms/WebForms_1/Topics/Caching/CachingUsingTheSqlDataSource.aspx)

#### ASPX

```
    <asp:SqlDataSource runat="server" ID="sds"
        ConnectionString="<%$ConnectionStrings:pubsConnectionString %>"
        CacheDuration="30"
        EnableCaching="true"
        SelectCommand="select * from jobs"
        DataSourceMode="DataSet"
        OnSelecting="sds_Selecting">

    </asp:SqlDataSource>
    <div>
        <asp:Literal runat="server" ID="msg" Mode="Encode"></asp:Literal>
    </div>
    <asp:GridView runat="server" DataSourceID="sds"></asp:GridView>
```

### Edit 1

In order to fire the trigger selectively when using SqlCacheDependency, you would need to update the triggers generated manually.

When you configure a table by using the `aspnet_regsql -t -et...` command, a trigger is added to the specified table. This trigger is in charge to populate the `AspNet_SqlCacheTablesForChangeNotification` table used by the SqlCacheDependency object to poll data from the database.

The trigger looks like:

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[jobs_AspNet_SqlCacheNotification_Trigger] ON [dbo].[jobs]
                   FOR INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE AS BEGIN
                   SET NOCOUNT ON
                   EXEC dbo.AspNet_SqlCacheUpdateChangeIdStoredProcedure N'jobs'
                   END
```

You could update the trigger to just call the `dbo.AspNet_SqlCacheUpdateChangeIdStoredProcedureN'jobs'` stored procedure when the rows you are interested in are updated

I'm not a SQL expert, but I think it would be easy to find a clean way to detect the rows that have changed, for example, googling I just found this link

[Most efficient method to detect column change in MS SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/651524/most-efficient-method-to-detect-column-change-in-ms-sql-server)

Comment: But this looks like you're caching the entire table? Is it possible to cache/invalidate based on single rows?

Comment: If u mean the rows returned by the `SqlDataSource` that depends on your query. If you refer to the SqlCacheDependency, it only caches **whaever u pull from the database** and your cached object will be invalidated **when a row in the specified table changes**. In this case, you cannot narrow your trigger to use just some rows. Remember that `SqlCacheDependency` is just a dependency used to remove your object from the cache, you could actually place any kind of object in the cache and attach it a SqlCacheDependency. It doesn't have to be from ur database although it should...

Comment: Yeah, see this doesn't work as other users will be changing rows all the time so I don't want to invalidate when any row changes, only the row I've cached. I need a more granular caching/notification.

Comment: Well actually I think you could do although it won't be "out of the box". I have not tried but I think it will work. I gonna update my answer

Answer (score 2):

[`SqlCacheDependency`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.caching.sqlcachedependency.aspx), as well as [`SqlDependency`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldependency.aspx), can do exactly what you describe. Both are based on [Query Notifications](http://rusanu.com/2006/06/17/the-mysterious-notification/), a technology that allows your application to receive notifications from the server when a row was updated. You can even leverage it from [LINQ](http://code.google.com/p/linqtocache/).

But you need to be wary, caching of values that change frequently can do more damage than good. You should only do this with values that are fairly stable.