# Update field in a table with trigger after insert and update

Tags: sql-server, database, triggers

I have a trigger in a database.

```
CREATE TRIGGER trigg_varer_ledit_iu
ON items
FOR INSERT, UPDATE
AS
BEGIN
    UPDATE items
    SET lastedit = GETDATE()
    WHERE itemnr IN (SELECT
    itemnr
    FROM inserted)
END;
```

It works good. Every time I update and insert new data to items the "lastEdit" field is updated.

But: I have some spesific fields in that table that should NOT trigger to update this lastEdit field. How can I achieve that?

Now it works for every fields that is updated. I need to keep some of them out of the circus.

Comment: i think you can have the logic in the trigger itself to check if the said column is being updated and then return back with out any processing

Comment: Any example of that?

Comment: You can use [`update(colname)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187326.aspx) function to check a single column or [`columns_updated()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186329.aspx) to check multiple columns.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an if construct to check.  For example on updates inserted.column = deleted.column

Related question - [Compare deleted and inserted table in SQL Server 2008](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23286636/compare-deleted-and-inserted-table-in-sql-server-2008)