# Writing trigger on a column

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers

Is it possible to write an update trigger which executes only if the particular column is updated?

eg: I have a table `Table1` with columns `column1`, `column2`, `column3`.

I want to create an update trigger which executes only if the `column3` is updated.

Comment: you can refer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/651524/most-efficient-method-to-detect-column-change-in-ms-sql-server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot write a trigger that only executes if `column3` is updated - the trigger is **on the table** and will fire every time something on the *table* changes.

But inside the trigger, you *can* check to see if `column3` has been updated, and if it has, you can do something.

Something like

```
CREATE TRIGGER updateTrigger
ON dbo.YourTableName
AFTER UPDATE
AS
    -- the "deleted" pseudo table contains the old values before the update,
    -- the "Inserted" table the new values after the update
    -- but DO REMEMBER: the trigger is run **once per statement** - so 
    -- both tables will most likely contain *multiple rows* and you need
    -- to work with that
    -- Scenario here: insert data into an "Audit" table if "column3" changed
    INSERT INTO dbo.Audit (ID, OldValueCol3, NewValueCol3)
        SELECT
            d.Id, d.Column3, i.Column3
        FROM 
            Deleted d
        INNER JOIN
            Inserted i ON d.ID = i.ID  -- join on the primary key
        WHERE
            d.Column3 <> i.Column3     -- use those rows where "column3" changed
```